# When using openpdf, can I add a Paragraph in the Paragraph with style attributes?

Tags: java, pdf, paragraph, openpdf

When I add a paragraph in the paragraph, some style attributes including alignment are not applied to the paragraph inside.
I need it to use a paragraph with a title and body and use it repeatedly.
(iText5 works well. however openpdf does not work.)

### OpenPdf Code

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.add("OUTER");
paragraph.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
Paragraph innerParagraph = new Paragraph();
innerParagraph.add("INNER");
innerParagraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
paragraph.add(innerParagraph);

Document document = new Document();
document.add(paragraph);
```

### Expect

```
OUTER
                                    INNER
```

### Result

```
OUTER
INNER
```